# How to handle Flash objects using Selenium Web Driver

Tags: selenium

How to handle Flash objects to perform some actions in my application. i am unable to identify the element. can any one help me for this issue

Comment: Kindly share your html and the element you want to identify

Answer (score 1):

Selenium automates Web browsers.

From http://seleniumhq.org..

> Selenium automates browsers. That's it.

Flash objects are impossible to automate using Selenium as flash objects are not technically 'browser driven' like javascript is.  You'll have to find other software to automate Flash.

Source - I am a contributor / maintainer of the project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ruby language for Selenium-Webdriver automation then you can use "Gem SIKULI" using which we can deal with all Flash elements. http://rubygems.org/gems/sikuli

But it is not that much reliable.

Gem sikuli needs Jruby i.e Java+Ruby

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. All you can do is do some clicking based on the coordinates, but this is really unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to automate flash objects with selenium as selenium is only for HTML so you can use 3rd party API Sikuli for this purpose sikuli provides image based automation in which you take image of an object and then use that image as reference to  perform your operation .So in other words in sikuli object identification is done via image processing

please check following simple blog posts to learn about usage of sikuli 
[Automating flash calculator with sikuli integration with selenium.](http://testingtoolstecniques.blogspot.com/2015/04/using-sikuli-api-with-selenium-web.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add the flashdriver jar into your project and then use the FlashWebDriver method to operate the Flash file.